# get current kubernetes logged in user with kprobe

Tags: kubernetes, linux-kernel, audit-logging, kprobe

I want to get currently logged in user for auditing. for example I want to find which user executed a malicious caommand in k8s pod. there is a tool that I can define some policy that can works with kprobe.
Is there anyway to get user by kprobe? I mean is there any call that return this for me?
I tried to use from k8s client libraries but it's not efficient for my task.